# Datastore Write Operations limit exceeding

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using Java SDK of app-engine.
I am using Master-slave datastore.
I have only two tables, each having 30 columns and none of them has size greater than 20 bytes.
After entering 300 rows in each table, it shows Datastore write operations 0.03 Millions out of 0.05 Millions.
I have checked the tables. They contain 300 entries only. There is no infinite loop kind of bug in my code.
Would someone please help me to point me out where I might be going wrong?

Thanks,
Amrish.

Comment: It would probably help if you could post the code that's doing the writes.

Comment: for(int i=0;i<list_flightinfo.size();i++)

          {
           System.out.println(list_flightinfo.get(i).toString());

Entity db_flightinfo = new Entity(src + "_" + dest);

          list_flightinfo.get(i).store_entity(db_flightinfo);}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As noted in the previous answer, those write totals include your index writes.
All entity properties have associated default indexes (unless the property is configured to be unindexed), even if you have not defined any custom indexes.

See http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection.html for more detail, and http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/billing.html#Billable_Resource_Unit_Cost for more specifics on write costs.
For example, a new entity 'put' is:
2 Writes + 2 Writes per indexed property value (these are for the default indexes for that property) + 1 Write per composite index value (for any relevant custom indexes that you have defined).

Answer (score 4):

Datastore writer operations include index updates. Make sure you don't have any [exploding indexes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Big_Entities_and_Exploding_Indexes). Keep in mind also that by default all fields have a built-in index; make any fields that you're not using unindexed to save quota.

Also, for better reliability and availability, consider switching to the high-reliability datastore (this doesn't directly fix your problem though).

Comment: Yeah, I chose this one because I needed 1 GB space for my purpose instead 500 MB. Also, I am not using any indexes.

Comment: @user925666, I believe HRD has the same free quotas as master slave. If you're not using any kind of crazy indexes, then your application really is making on the order of 10,000 write requests (multiply number of puts by the number of fields plus one to account for default indexes).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem due to size of `list_flightinfo`. Also, this code might have been called several times per second.

The key of the entity is:

```
src+"_"+dest
```

Which is not getting changed in the loop, hence same entity is getting overwritten again and again.